# requirejs module slow loading causing null pointers in other parts of javascript framework

Tags: javascript, ajax, requirejs

We have started using requirejs in our javascript framework however we have noticed a problem that only seems to occur in firefox.

When a request comes from the server it contains the html and javascript of the components (button, label, checkbox, etc) we want to display. 
The javscript will contains component specific information. For example what color the text should in a label.

A simple example would be

```
<button type="button" id="button123">Test</button>
require(['BUTTONDEPENDENCY'], function() {
    register("button123");
    console.log("component info");
    ...
});
```

This shim is something like.

```
BUTTONDEPENDENCY = /js/button.js
```

The request also contains a JSON array which contains information about those components (I won't go into to detail about them).
The JSON array is executed after the html/javascript is loaded on the browser.

When executing each object in the JSONArray I need to execute a `getComponent()` function. When it tried to execute `getComponent('button123')` it cannot be found because the require function has not been execute (needs to do `register("button123");`). It does actually get executed but after it can't be found. I dont see this problem in Chrome so I am guessing this is timing issue (Chrome loading the dependency faster?)

Why does it work fine in Chrome?

Why is it taking longer to load even though when have loaded to module before?

Should I force the javascript to wait before doing getComponent until register has execute? This might lead to problems in our application

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is just the way RequireJS works.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload

For instance in the following code, I believe you will get the 2nd alert before the 1st:

```
<script>
require(['foo'], function(foo){
    alert(1);
});
</script>
<!-- lots of HTML -->
<script>
    alert(2);
</script>
```